# Debounce inotifywait for large files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, inotify

I upload files for deployment into a remote directory. That remote server has a script that watches the directory for new files:

```bash
inotifywait --monitor --event create --format '%f' --quiet /foo
```

When a new file is detected, the deployment process starts.

The problem is the upload takes time - and the file is detected as soon as it starts writing. So the deployment fails as it attempts to use a partial file.

Is there a way to debounce the `inotifywait` so it reports the new file only after it is fully created?

Comment: You shouldn't be watching for `create`; you should be looking for `close` or `close_write`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have experienced, watching for `create` events isn't very useful: these events trigger when the file is created, but that doesn't tell you if any data has been written to it, nor do you know when something has *finished* writing data to it.

You will generally want to monitor the `close` or `close_write` events. From the man page:

> ### EVENTS
>
> - `close_write`
>
>   A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed,
>   after being opened in writeable mode.  This does not necessarily
>   imply the file was written to.
> - `close_nowrite`
>
>   A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed,
>   after being opened in read-only mode.
> - `close`
>
>   A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed,
>   regardless of how it was opened.  Note that this  is  actually
>   implemented  simply  by  listening  for  both  `close_write`  and
>   `close_nowrite`, hence all close events received will be output as
>   one of these, not CLOSE.